# WSO2 EMM can't login

Tags: wso2

I'm newbie on WSO2 MDM solution, I just finished setup the server. Now I want login https://server_ip:9443/emm/ with admin/admin , but after login will redirect to https://localhost:9443/emm/acs , you can see that not service IP address, how can I fix this problem ?

I just want login emm to register my Android mobile device.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using EMM 1.1.0 version. When you start the server you will see the emm url as follows

```
[2015-11-10 20:01:23,254]  INFO {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -  EMM URL : http://10.100.7.26:9763/emm
```

Just click on that. You will redirect to a single sign on page. There you can login using admin/admin. Then you will redirect back to the emm console. There you can register your android device.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited sso-idp-conifg.xml (localhost to ip_server) that can redirect to https://server_ip:9443/emm/  , anyway, thanks for your help.

Hello,

I just edited sso-idp-config (localhost to server_ip) that can redirect.